# Set Code Spell Checker ignore strings that start with a $

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and the [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker#overview) extension.
I'm trying to get Code Spell Checker to ignore strings that start with `$`

I'm no RegEx wiz but I think the proper regex for this is `^\$`

I've tried all number of options for `cSpell.ignoreRegExpList` including:

- `"cSpell.ignoreRegExpList": [ "^\\$" ]`
- `"cSpell.ignoreRegExpList": [ "^\$" ]`
- `"cSpell.ignoreRegExpList": [ "^/\$" ]`

with no luck.

Is it possible to set Code Spell Checker to ignore strings that start with `$` and if so, what's the correct way to set it in my User Settings file?

Comment: Try `^(?!\$)` or `^[^$]`

Comment: Are they supposed to be in quotes like that? Potentially try `"cSpell.ignoreRegExpList": [ ^\$ ]` or `"cSpell.ignoreRegExpList": [/^\$/]`

Comment: @ctwheels Nope, `^(?!\$)` does not like the `\` and `^[^$]` seems to ignore random first characters regardless

Comment: @jmcgriz I think it needs the quotes - both of your options cause errors in the User Settings file that VSCode complains about

Comment: Makes sense. It's odd, none of the examples I've found include `^` or `$`. It'd be strange if it doesn't support beginning and end of string syntax, but maybe? This issue references using the comment syntax, maybe try that route https://github.com/Jason-Rev/vscode-spell-checker/issues/27

Comment: I think it is difficult since that extension ignores "symbols".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regular expression need to match against the entire text to be ignored.

```
"cSpell.ignoreRegExpList": [
    "^\\$.+"
]
```

UPDATE:
Ahh, I misunderstood, I thought you wanted to ignore lines starting with $. To ignore words starting with $ use: `"\\$\\w+"`

Comment: That works...unless the line is indented, then it does not work.  `$fullpath = $path . '/test/';` shows that fullpath is spelled wrong.  If I add what you recommended to my user settings file it works but if I have  `$fullpath = $path . '/test/';` (with a leading tab) it sill shows fullpath as spelled wrong.   `$fullpath = $path . '/test/';` (with one leading space) does the same.  I'm guessing it looks at the entire line...?

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood, I thought you wanted to ignore lines starting with $.
To ignore words starting with $ use: `"\\$\\w+"`